# Best open source IT ticket system that works well with AD for authentication

Tags: active-directory, server, ticket-system

I work for a company that wants to go with an open source IT ticket system that is easy to integrate for the users on our domain. We want them to be able to login with their user accounts that are on the domain. The ticket system does not have to be super modern. We just want something that will work for us and we can track on the ticket system instead of using email which is a bad way of managing the IT problems we come across. Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW the number of computers that we manage are between 90-140 systems. About 30-40 network printers.

Comment: Nothing came up with that link you provided. We are wanting something that will work with exchange as well. So anytime a ticket is updated it will email a status.

Comment: Sorry, softwarerecs.stackexchange.com